# Not getting out of the While Loop

Tags: c

i wrote a loop and i thought that case 4 will get me out of the loop. Somehow it doesnt.

```
while (menu == 1)
{
    printf("you made it.");
}

while (menu == 2)
{
    int freeSlots = calcFreeSlots(inventar, sizeInv);
    int optionsInv = optionsInvQuestion(); //returns an OptionValue for the InvMenuOptions

    switch (optionsInv)
    {
    case 1: //openInv
        printInv(inventar, sizeInv, freeSlots);
        break;

    case 2: //removeItem
        printf("Not Implemented\n");
        break;
    
    case 3: //addItem
        printf("Not Implemented\n");
        break;
        
    case 4: //exitInvMenu
        menu = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

I tried asking ChatGPT. its not helping.

Comment: @Peter Kirsch Why is the first loop while (menu == 1)
{
    printf("you made it.");
} infinite?

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: You never modify `menu` in the first loop. I suspect it should be `if`, not `while`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the above code snipped enters in second while loop, and if the value of **optionsInv** is **4** then it will definitely exit the loop

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int menu = 2;

  //  while (menu == 1)
  // {
  //     printf("you made it.");
  // }

  while (menu == 2) {
    // int freeSlots = calcFreeSlots(inventar, sizeInv);
    // int optionsInv = optionsInvQuestion(); //returns an OptionValue for the InvMenuOptions
    int optionsInv = 4;

    switch (optionsInv) {
    case 1: //openInv
      printf("inside case 1\n");
      // printInv(inventar, sizeInv, freeSlots);
      break;

    case 2: //removeItem
      printf("inside case 2");
      printf("Not Implemented\n");
      break;

    case 3: //addItem
      printf("inside case 3");
      printf("Not Implemented\n");
      break;

    case 4: //exitInvMenu
      printf("inside case 4\n");
      menu = 1;
      break;
    }
  }

  printf("outside loop");
  return 0;
}
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: thx a lot! i guess i was to tired to see it. your printf statements clarified it. thank you. My mistake was that i thought it is going to (while menu==1) loop. I can see that it is not how code works. it will simply exit after the while (menu == 2) loop and end. i will find a way.

Comment: @PeterKirsch you're welcome